# Include Elements in XSD Complex Type Without New Element

Tags: xsd, element, complextype

I have this complex type:

```
<xsd:complexType name="Identifier">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="Id" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="Version" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Now I want to include this in another complex type and I've been doing that like this:

```
<xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="Id" type="Identifier"/>
              <!-- More elements here -->
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

This isn't what I really want though.  I want to include the Identifier type's elements directly in my second complex type without creating a new element.  E.g. the same as just doing this:

```
<xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="Id" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="Version" type="xsd:string"/>
              <!-- More elements here -->
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Hope that makes sense.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can extend types, like this:

```
<xsd:complexType name="MySubType">
    <xsd:complexContent>
        <xsd:extension base="Identifier">
                       <xsd:sequence>
                            <!-- More elements here -->
                       </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Comment: Perfect - thanks.  Do you know how to include multiple extensions in a single complex type?

Comment: Found the answer.  What I wanted was multiple inheritance, which can be achieved using xsd:group.

Comment: Aye, groups are very handy things, although they can get confusing if you over-do it.

Answer (score 1):

this complex type will always resolve to

```
<Identifier>
   <Id>string</Id>
   <Version>string</Version>
</Identifier>
```

if you don't want a child structure, you could define Id and Version as elements and reference them using

```
<xsd:element ref="Id"/>
<xsd:element ref="Version"/>
```

later on. But then you don't have the guarantee that they both occur

You can also make Id and Version attributes to the Identifier element in a complex type

good luck
Mike